# Array merging with different values and not for same values of the key

Tags: php, arrays

The following array has same key and value but amenities only I need to merge them both

```
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [room_id] => 15
                        [room] => deluxee
                        [price] => 2000.00
                        [amenities] => Swimming Pool
                        [photo_path] => 1\15\11790549875ba35c08e26b6.jpg
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [room_id] => 15
                        [room] => deluxee
                        [price] => 2000.00
                        [amenities] => Double Bedroom
                        [photo_path] => 1\15\11790549875ba35c08e26b6.jpg
                    )
```

So I need the output what can i do??

```
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [room_id] => 15
                        [room] => deluxee
                        [price] => 2000.00
                        [amenities] => stdClass Object
                                           (
                                           [0] => Swimming Pool
                                           [1] =>Double Bedroom
                                            )
                        [photo_path] => 1\15\11790549875ba35c08e26b6.jpg
                    )
```

Comment: You can write some code and share it with us. We can tell what is wrong with your code. But we __will not write__ code for you.

Comment: i used  array_merge_recursive() but that merges all the keys of  the array . So  is there any other functions to do the this

Comment: There's a `foreach` loop that solves all the problems.

Comment: oh... okay i'll try